# How to disable the log a call from the Chatter feed in Salesforce1 app

Tags: chatter, salesforce1-app, mobile

I'm having a problem of trying to resolve this issue. My business user is complaining that after they enter the info in log a call by making a call directly through the Salesforce1 mobile app. Their log a call details are showing in their Chatter feed.  They claims that they had the option not to sending it to Chatter but after the recent update of the Salesforce1 mobile app, and they couldn't do it anymore.  Would it be possible to prevent the users to show the log a call info in Chatter?

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how the user is calling the action, this might be related to using a true "publisher action" instead of "Mobile Smart Actions."

- The Log a Call action supplied in Mobile Smart Actions uses the
  standard page layout to create a task record, and as such, does not
  create a Chatter feed item (you might be able to do it with feed tracking, but it doesn't happen by default).
- The Log a Call publisher action uses the action layout. This allows
  you to have a different form for creation versus editing, but Create 
  a Record and Log a Call action types both create a Chatter feed item.
  At the moment there is no way to prevent the feed item creation.

Prior to Summer '14, orgs that had the Chatter > Publisher Actions pref disabled got Mobile Smart Actions by default. As of Summer '14, you can use publisher actions in Salesforce1 regardless of whether they're enabled in Chatter in the web UI.

So, if your user is using the + icon on a record or the Feed page to log a call, check Global Actions > Publisher Layouts or the object page layout and see whether you're using Mobile Smart Actions or a Log a Call action.

You can remove the Log a Call action and use Mobile Smart Actions instead. But, the list of Mobile Smart Actions isn't configurable, and the forms can't be optimized for mobile in the way that a true publisher action can be, so there's a tradeoff. Also Mobile Smart Actions don't appear in the publisher in the web app (which you may or may not care about). Being able to have Create a Record/Log a Call actions that don't create a feed item is on that team's roadmap but I don't know how far out it is.

For more information on the changes that occurred in Summer '14, see the Release Notes:

- [Changes to Mobile Smart Actions Behavior](http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/summer14/release-notes/rn_forcecom_actions_msa_changes.htm)
- [Publisher Enabled for Chatter Off Organizations](http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/summer14/release-notes/rn_forcecom_actions_nochatter.htm)

Comment: Hi Shannon, I checked my environment that it's using the Mobile Smart Actions in the Account page layout.  However, the original problem is the business user is using the "log a call" after they make the call thru the Salesforce 1 mobile app.   When click on the "phone" icon in the account, there are two options: call the phone number or log a call without calling. If they create a "log a call" by choosing "log a call without calling" or "log a call" after call the phone number.  The info will show in the Chatter feed. And they don't want to show this.

Comment: The phone icon always uses a publisher action (I believe it uses either the first Log a Call type action on the page layout, or the default OOB one if there isn't one on the layout) so it's going to post to the Chatter feed. You can suggest that the user uses the Mobile Smart Action until the ability to disable actions from posting to the feed comes in.